# total order on all functions of natural numbers

Tags: functions, relations

My discrete math textbook has a question: let $f$ be a set of all functions  from $\mathcal{N}$ to $\mathcal{N}$. $K$ is a relation onto $f$. For $(f,g) \in f$: $(f,g) \in K$ iff for all $n\in \mathcal{N}$, $f(n) \le g(n)$. We need to prove that $K$ is not a total order onto $f$. I can define a function $f$ such that $$f(1) = 2; f(2)=1;f(n)=n$$ where $n \notin\{1,2\}$. Similarly, we can define a function $g$ such that
$$g(1) = 1; g(2)=2;g(n)=n$$ where $n \notin\{1,2\}$. Does this prove that the function is not a total order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does. $f$ and $g$ are incomparable according to $R$ since $g(1)<f(1)$ but $f(2)<g(2)$.

Comment: so when we determine if $f$ and $g$ are comparable we look at all the possibilities of the given $f$ and $g$? Because if compare the specific cases of $f$ and $g$, for example when f=1 and g=1 we can compare them.

Comment: Since the relation demands for all natural numbers $f(n)≤g(n)$ so it suffices to put forward only one counterexample to show that they are  not comparable.

Comment: You mean "since $g(1) < f(1)$ but $f(2) < g(2)$." It is not enough that $g(1) \le f(1)$ and $f(2)\le g(2)$.

Comment: $f$ is "larger" than $g$ if $f$ is greater than $g$ **at each point**.Totality says that for **any**  $f$ and $g$ one is "larger" than other. But the functions the OP gave, shows that there is pair of functions such that neither one is "larger" than other, therefore the order is not total.

Comment: @AsharTafhim: You have completely missed my point.

Comment: @TonyK then can you elaborate please?

Comment: @AsharTafhim: Just read my initial comment. Read it _carefully_.

Comment: OK i got what you are saying. Thanks!